# I can share files between Docker containers, how do I share the same files with the host

Tags: docker, volumes

I have a number of containers running of a Pi4 as defined by a docker-compose.yml file (extract below).  They collect data from a piece of hardware which records data to /home/hardware/data/ on the “hardware” container.  This is successfully shared with the “celery_worker” container via the “data” named volume.

My problem is I also need the files to be shared onto the host (e.g. /tmp/hardware_data), because they need to be read by another application on another machine on my home network.

- /tmp/hardware_data:/home/hardware/data/    does not work.

I have googled, read the Docker documentation and watched a number of youtube videos, but am no nearer a solution.

```
celery_worker:
    image: celery_worker:latest
    container_name: celery_worker
    volumes:
      - data:/srv/project/hardware/hardware_data/

hardware:
    image: hardware:latest
    container_name: hardware
    volumes:
      - data:/home/hardware/data/

volumes:
  #to share hardware data
  data: {}
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Update

Konrad’s advice on getting rid of the named volumes made sense and my (extract) docker-compose.yml file now looks like this:

```
celery_worker:
    image: celery_worker:latest
    container_name: celery_worker
    volumes:
      - /tmp/hardware_data:/srv/project/hardware/hardware_data/

hardware:
    image: hardware:latest
    container_name: hardware
    volumes:
      - /tmp/hardware_data:/home/hardware/data/
```

Whilst in development I am running Docker as root.  I have “touched” a “test file” in the hardware container’s Dockerfile.  If I run the containers with the volumes #’d out, the “test file” is created in /home/hardware/data/ on the hardware’s container with the following permissions “- r w-r - -r- - root root .

When I run docker-compose.yml with the volumes defined I get three empty directories (2 in containers 1 in host) i.e. the hardware container’s “test file” is not present in any of the directories.  If I “touch” a “new test file” in any of the directories it is shared across all three with the same permissions as the original “test file”:  “- r w- r - - r - - root root”.

Based on this I can't see that it is a permissions issue

Comment: I would imagine that this is because you have both a docker volume and a local volume bound to the same path on the container. Not 100% sure, but this seems the most likely to me

Comment: Sorry,could you tell me,what's the differce,between `mount /tmp/hardware_data onto /home/hardware/data/` and    `mount /home/hardware/data/ onto /tmp/hardware_data`?In my thoughts,they are the same.

Comment: Thank you both.  Perhaps I am just confusing the situation.  The named volume works fine.  Ignore how I have tried to solve it becuase it doesn't work.   How do I share the files produced in the docker hardware container in /home/hardware/data/ with my host ?   I have amended my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

I got some clues from here: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-access-docker-volume-data-from-host-machine/88063
Meyay’s answer “Only with named volumes existing data is copied from the container target folder into the volume.”

This code works.  Please note: /tmp/data must pre-exist on the host, with the same permissions (and owner I think) as the docker container.

```
celery_worker:
    image: celery_worker:latest
    container_name: celery_worker
    volumes:
      - data:/srv/project/hardware/hardware_data/

hardware:
    image: hardware:latest
    container_name: hardware
    volumes:
      - data:/home/hardware/data/

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /tmp/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the named volume and use a folder on the host machine, like this:

```
celery_worker:
    image: celery_worker:latest
    container_name: celery_worker
    volumes:
      - /tmp/hardware_data:/srv/project/hardware/hardware_data/

hardware:
    image: hardware:latest
    container_name: hardware
    volumes:
      - /tmp/hardware_data:/home/hardware/data/
```

Edit:

Without any details of the application running in hardware service, the only reason I can think of why it would not write data to the bound host directory is an issue of permissions.

[Here](https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca)'s an article about this topic.

Comment: The way I understood your setup was that they should start empty and then hardware service would fill them with data.

Comment: Sorry I needed to delete my previous coment as it contained some confidential information.  Here it is again...............Thank you very much. That makes sense and sounded promising, but on trying it.....all three directories are empty. I think your answer is on the right track but isn’t the problem here that I am mounting an empty host directory /tmp/hardware_data onto /home/hardware/data/ in a container, making it look empty ?

Comment: "The way I understood your setup was that they should start empty and then hardware service would fill them with data. "........   That's correct Konrad all three directories start empty and the hardware fills the /home/hardware/data directory in the hardware container.    If I put a file into the host directory then it appears in the containers.  I need it to happen the other way around.  Data put into a container needs to be shared with another container and the host.

Comment: So the issue with my solution is that hardware sevice does not fill the directory? Are there some sort of logs available? Maybe permissions on the `/tmp/hardware_data` directory are incorrect?

Comment: Thanks Konrad.  1) The hardware service fills the hardware directory with no volumes defined.  2) It fills and shares the data (with other containers) using a named volume but 3) Once I define a host:container volume all directories are blank.

Comment: I have given the host directory 'ugo+rwx' permisssions, no change

Comment: Unless hardware service logs the reason of why it's not writing the data, I don't know what else you could try.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share with you the complete solution that you can use to share files via the Docker network between containers in a portable way without using Volumes or installing `ssh` in the Docker container.

**A simple bash function that exposes the file on the source machine:**

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make the file available for another machine via the network
#
# this runs in the background to avoid blocking the main script execution
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function exposeFile() {
    local file port
    file="$1"
    port=1384

    echo "exposing the file for another machine with..."
    echo "   file: $file"
    echo "   port: $port"

    while :
    do
        { echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"; cat "$file" ; } | nc  -l "$port"
    done
}
```

The endless loop is necessary if you want to download the file more than one time because after the download `Netcat` exists.

**Call the bash method from your main script to expose the file when you need it:**

```
#!/bin/bash
...
exposeFile "path/to/the/file.zip" &
```

**Then you can use the a simple `wget` to download the file on the source machine:**

```
function fileDownload {
    echo "downloading the file..."

    local fileHome file
    fileHome="/download/directory/"
    file="myfile.zip"

    local remoteHost remotePort
    remoteHost="remote-host-or-ip"
    remotePort=1384

    mkdir -p "$fileHome"
    wget -O "$fileHome/$file" "$remoteHost":"$remotePort"
}
```

I hope that this will help you to save some time ;)